# DELETE methods not callable

Tags: restler

I don't seem to be able to call DELETE methods via Restler for some reason.  In my restler php file I've defined a method like so:

```php
    /**
     * Drop invitation
     *
     * Removes an invitation from the system.  Coaches want a way to be able
     * to remove an invite if they messed up, or the person just doesn't accept.
     *
     * @param string $email The email address of the invited person {@from body}
     * @param int $team_id The SQL identifier for the team {@from body}
     *
     * @return array An empty array
     */
    public function deleteInvite($email, $team_id) {
            return [];
    }
```

When I try to call it:

> curl -X DELETE -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"email":"foo","team_id",17}' http://*server.com*/app/team/invite

It comes back with a 400 error:

> {
>       "error": {
>           "code": 400,
>           "message": "Bad Request: email is missing."
>       }
>   }

How am I supposed to be calling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a widely accepted practice restler does not support/read body parameters for `GET` and `DELETE` requests. Send them on url or as a query string instead.

As you can see in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-26#section-4.3

- **HEAD** - No defined body semantics.
- **GET** - No defined body semantics.
- **PUT** - Body supported.
- **POST** - Body supported.
- **DELETE** - No defined body semantics.
- **TRACE** - Body **not** supported.
- **OPTIONS** - Body supported but no semantics (maybe in the future).

Many http servers do not parse the body of `GET` and `DELETE` requests, restler is following that practice

Comment: Thanks.  Why is this a "best practice"?